# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 freeze completely and frequently?

Tags: 16.04, freeze

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on a 64-bit dell netbook (Pentium (R) CPU N3700). But ever since the install, it encounters complete freezing when no key and mouse click works. All I can do is to force shut down using power button. It happens randomly, sometimes soon after booting, sometimes when I'm browsing or I'm typing a document. I'm in a beginner level of Ubuntu. What should I do?

Comment: Prime suspect would be a driver issue; secondary suspects hardware issues including memory failures.

How much RAM do  you have? Is this the only OS installed? Are any proprietary drivers suggested by Driver Manager?

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu in parallel to Windows 10 which is working okay. There are no suggestions from Driver Manager.

Comment: It may be a long process... Check `/var/log/syslog` for the last messages before the reboot. Post the details of your video driver and wireless driver (wireless used to be a big source of issues, less so in recent releases). Does the netbook feel particularly hot?

Comment: How much swap space do you have? `swapon` will show.